# Issue Formatting EditText for Currency

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, currency

All- I have been struggling with this for a while and have looked at all the other questions about this sort of thing but I just can't figure it out: I have an edttext field that needs to be formatted for currency. I have tried the code in all of the other questions relating to this but no matter what I try it just doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);  

    text.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);    

    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
            {
                String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                if (userInput.length() > 0) {
                    Float in=Float.parseFloat(userInput);
                    float percen = in/100;
                    text.setText("$"+dec.format(percen));
                    text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is inside of an onClick method. Does that make a difference (eg. the text will only be formatted when the user clicks the button)?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`onTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) does not work like that. You cannot modify the text in `onTextChanged`.

Comment: Ok, so how would I format it for currency? afterTextChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this method in the past for formatting money.

```
static public String customFormat(String pattern, double s ) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    String stringFormatOutput = myFormatter.format(s);
    return stringFormatOutput;
 }
```

it can be used like this:

```
String strPrice = customFormat("$###,##0.00", 300.2568);
mTxt.setText(strPrice);
```

just change the "300.2568" to be your price. This probably could work just as well for floats instead of doubles.